# How can I find the node given a position of a linkedlist?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nullpointerexception

```
public class Practice{
    private Node head;
    private int count = 0;

    public class Node{
        private char data;
        private Node next;

        private Node(char data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null; 
        }
    }

  public Practice() {
    head = null;
  }
 public Character getData(int position) {

 }
}
```

is there a way to find the node within a linkedlist if I have a parameter position? 
so if I have a linkedlist of characters "question" and position is 2, then this method should return 'e'

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just take one step through the list for each `position`:

```
public Character getData(int position) {
  Node current = head;
  while(position > 0) {
    current = current.next;
    position--;
  }
  return current.data;
}
```

You may need to add some `if` statements or `try`/`catch` pairs to deal with out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: We shouldn't be doing their homework when they have shown no effort. Traversing a LinkedList is one of the most basic problems, the solution and explanation to which is available on so many websites.

Comment: How do you know I didn't try this method? I traced my every step traversing through the linkedlist on paper and I keep getting a nullpointerException. I tried looking online and couldn't find anything related to this error. Even this method still gives me the same error.

Comment: @KAI Think about what happens when `position` is larger than the size of the linked list. Or the linked list is empty.